# How can I make the control can not be click while overlying?

Tags: wpf

I make an easy demo by WPF, here is the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="Grid_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Background="White">
        <Border Height="100" Width="100" Background="Red" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="Border_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"></Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And here is the code-behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void Border_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Border");
        }

        private void Grid_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Grid");
        }
    }
}
```

I wanna do that if I press the border, it only activates the "Border" message box but not with the "Grid" message box also.

How can I do it? Would you please help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Just use MouseLeftButtonDown instead of PreviewMouseLeftButonDown for border will solve your problem.

Comment: The grid should use PreviewMouseDown and the border should use MouseDown. It works!@Smits

Comment: I found something mistake. If I use the messagebox.show(), all is ok. But after I change it as console.writeline() or any other function. The grid and the border will active both. How can I solve it? Thank you. @Smits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can replace PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown with MouseDown.

Comment: The grid should use PreviewMouseDown and the border should use MouseDown. It works!

Comment: I found something mistake. If I use the messagebox.show(), all is ok. But after I change it as console.writeline() or any other function. The grid and the border will active both. How can I solve it? Thank you.